# Can't read values of mat-select with multiple tag

Tags: angular

I have this portion on my html page:

```
<form name="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>

...
    
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex>
                <mat-label>{{'nazione' | translate}}</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="nazione" [compareWith]="compareId" required multiple
                  (selectionChange)="onNazioneChange($event.value)">
                  <mat-option>
                    <ngx-mat-select-search class="select" [formControl]="nazioniFilter" placeholderLabel="Cerca..."
                      noEntriesFoundLabel="'Nessuna corrispondenza...'">
                    </ngx-mat-select-search>
                  </mat-option>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let nazione of this.nazioniFiltered" [value]="nazione">
                    {{nazione.id}} - {{nazione.descrizioneIT}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
```

and on my component I get the form values with `this.myForm.getRawValue();`
If I read form whitout tag `multiple` on `mat-select` all works fine, but if I put `multiple` tag the value `nazione` return empty.
What's I make wrong?

My data is a array of nations:

```
[
  { id: 'AF', descrizioneIT: 'Afganistan' },
  { id: 'AL', descrizioneIT: 'Albania' },
  { id: 'DZ', descrizioneIT: 'Algeria' },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

The problem was we were not checking the ID for `value` (`[value]="nazione.id"`)

Please check you `compareWith` method, below is an example, where it works.

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

/**
 * @title Mat-Select Multiple initialisation with ngModel
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  nazioniFiltered: any[] = [
    { id: 'AF', descrizioneIT: 'Afganistan' },
    { id: 'AL', descrizioneIT: 'Albania' },
    { id: 'DZ', descrizioneIT: 'Algeria' },
  ];
  myselectedFoods = ['AF', 'AL'];
  foodForm: FormControl = new FormControl(this.myselectedFoods);

  compareId(o1: any, o2: any) {
    return o1 === o2;
  }
}
```

html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select
    [formControl]="foodForm"
    [compareWith]="compareId"
    required
    multiple
    (selectionChange)="onNazioneChange($event.value)"
  >
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let nazione of this.nazioniFiltered"
      [value]="nazione.id"
    >
      {{nazione.id}} - {{nazione.descrizioneIT}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

{{foodForm.value | json}}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-multi-with-formcontrol-gnphly)

Comment: Thank you Narem for you answer. In my code I always use this compare function
```compareId(o1: any, o2: any) {
    return o1 && o2 ? o1.id == o2.id : false;
  }```
I tried with yours but nothing changed

Comment: @Rinos please share the list data inorder to debug, if possible plz modify the stackblitz and replicate the scenario and share in the question

Comment: @Rinos updated my answer!